# RISC-V function prologue 48-bit mystery shifts

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I am passing a 32-bit packed value to a function inside a sandbox, and then I am pretending it's a struct in the guest. All is well, but there are some mystery instructions in the prologue:

```
uint16_t stdCactusVisibility(Block src, Block dst, uint16_t facing)
{
    // Only add sides if cacti meet
    if (src.getID() == dst.getID())
        return_fast(facing & (1 | 2 | 16 | 32));
    return_fast(facing);
}
```

The struct is a wrapper around 2x 16-bit integers:

```
struct Block {
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t otherbits;
};
```

Simplified version.

```
stdCactusVisibility():
  4010c0:       03059593                slli    a1,a1,0x30
  4010c4:       03051513                slli    a0,a0,0x30
  4010c8:       0305d593                srli    a1,a1,0x30
  4010cc:       03055513                srli    a0,a0,0x30
  4010d0:       ff010113                addi    sp,sp,-16
  4010d4:       00a58663                beq     a1,a0,4010e0 <stdCactusVisibility+0x20>
  4010d8:       00060513                mv      a0,a2
  ...
```

What I am really wondering about is what those 48-bit shifts are trying to achieve?

I've tried: Making Block a union with 2 shared 16-bit members. No change.

I've tried: Unpacking the registers into Block the proper way. No change.

I've tried: Returning a full register value. No change.

My guess is that this is how RISC-V is creating a 16-bit value, which is the return value here, and also used in the ID comparison (a0 == a1). If so, that is quite annoying.

Is this a problematic area with RISC-V? Any ideas how to improve this? This is a type of function that is called ~billion-times in a very low-latency emulator. The reason why there is C++ inside is in order to reduce instruction counts by the magic of well-placed abstractions. The cost of a call is ~3ns in the worst case, but it can get ugly quickly if there are many instructions in the function.

Comment: Look like it's just zero-extending 16-bit to 64-bit for both args.  Baseline RISC-V unfortunately leaves out even a zero-extend and sign-extend instructions, so they have to use shifts for 16-bit.  (8-bit zext can use `andi`).  The zero/sign-extension instructions are probably part of extension b, so would come with a huge amount of complex bit-manipulation instructions.  The RISC-V calling convention might make this not always as bad when passing `uint16_t` or `int16_t` args, like sign-extending to 64-bit by default.

Comment: I started on Zbb but it's just too big to do without a good reason to implement it. I do have Zba at least, and Zbc is "just" carryless multiply.

Comment: I found a solution: Pass in the arguments as 4x 16-bit values (id, extra), (id, extra), facing. That solves the issue. Now the comparison is 1 instruction! It was your idea @PeterCordes

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of my point; RISC-V groups cheap, simple, somewhat valuable instructions into the same extension as a large number of other instructions, some of them somewhat complex.  So it's presumably common to *not* implement that extension, so no cheap sign or zero extension.  Having the caller pass 4 separate values instead of a struct solves the problem if your function can't or won't inline, but of course means at least 4 instructions in the caller instead of 1 to write a single register.

Comment: Unfortunately until I add binary translation, the emulator averages ~10+ instructions per bytecode. So it was an easy win in this case. The emulator is low latency in call overhead (setup and teardown) as well as in passing arguments to it. At some point it may be OK to do 4 shifts due to binary translation, but not right now.

Comment: In this case, clang makes better asm: it knows that high garbage doesn't affect the low 16 bits of an `add` result, even when that high garbage is other struct members, not just part of a wider integer which GCC can handle.  See my comments on 
pmacfarlane's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `src` and `dst` in as structures (rather than pointers). Each structure is passed in, in a register: `a0` and `a1` respectively.

They will be laid out like this:

```
[63-48]   [47-32]   [31-16]   [15-0]
 XXXX      XXXX     otherbits  id
```

After the left shift, each register will look like this:

```
[63-48]   [47-32]   [31-16]   [15-0]
   id      0000      0000      0000
```

Then after the right shift, like this:

```
[63-48]   [47-32]   [31-16]   [15-0]
 0000      0000      0000      id
```

So basically, it is extracting the `id` fields from your structs. It is a different way of doing `a0 &= 0xffff`. I guess the compiler feels this way is more efficient than constructing the mask and doing an `AND`.

Comment: We could test whether the compiler is even considering constructing a mask by passing more args this way, and seeing if the compiler spends 2 shifts for each, or that convinces it to spend 2 instructions to lui+ori (or whatever) to construct `0xffff` to save 4 instructions (4x `andi` instead of 4x pairs of shifts.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Pvr7cE7nT shows GCC missing that optimization of using AND for structs, but it will do it for `uint32_t` args that are added with `return (uint16_t)a + (uint16_t)b + ()c + ()d`  as a `uint32_t` return value. GCC also misses the fact that just doing 32 or 64-bit adds and truncating the sum at the end will produce the correct low 16 bits, whether the high garbage is another struct member or upper bits of a wider integer.

Comment: Clang does know that, only zero-extending *before* addition when necessary, like for `return (uint16_t)a + (uint16_t)b` as uint32_t, where implicit conversion of `uint16_t` to `int` means we're doing 32-bit addition of zero-extended values, producing a result that can have some bits set in the high 16.  So we do actually need zero-extended inputs.  (Clang agrees with GCC that materializing a constant for four `and` instructions is the way to go in that case.)  Otherwise clang just uses `add` and zero-extends the final result, even for low struct members.